# WPF bind IsEnabled on other controls if a listbox has a select item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, isenabled

I have a grid with 2 columns, a listbox in column 0 and a number of other controls in the a secondary grid in the main grids column 1.

I want this controls only to be enabled (or perhaps visible) if an items is selected in the listbox through binding.  I tried on a combo box:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding myList.SelectedIndex}"
```

But that does not seem to work.

Am I missing something?  Should something like this work?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You'll need a `ValueConverter` for this. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160210020233/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx) describes it in detail, but the summary is you need a public class that implements IValueConverter. In the Convert() method, you could do something like this:

```
if(!(value is int)) return false;
if(value == -1) return false;
return true;
```

Now, in your XAML, you need to do:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:YourValueConverter x:Key="MyValueConverter">
</Window.Resources>
```

And finally, modify your binding to:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding myList.SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}"
```

Are you sure you didn't mean

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=myList, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}"
```

though? You can't implicitly put the element's name in the path (unless the `Window` itself is the `DataContext`, I guess). It might also be easier to bind to SelectedItem and check for not null, but that's really just preference.

Oh, and if you're not familiar with alternate `xmlns` declarations, up at the top of your `Window`, add

```
xmlns:local=
```

and VS will prompt you for the various possibilities. You need to find the one that matches the namespace you put the valueconverter you made in.

Answer (score 2):

Copy-paste solution:

Add this class to your code:

```
public class HasSelectedItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is int && ((int) value != -1);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add converter as StaticResource to App.xml in `<Application.Resources>` section:

```
<local:HasSelectedItemConverter x:Key="HasSelectedItemConverter" />
```

And now you can use it in your XAML:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=listView1, Path=SelectedIndex,
 Converter={StaticResource HasSelectedItemConverter}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps it works with a BindingConverter, which converts explicitly all indexes > 0 to true.

Comment: An index of 0 is valid for a ListBox, though. You'd need to do true if > -1.